# What is max value can be entered as string for Integer.parseInt(String)

Tags: java

While parsing a string value to integer, i found `NumberFormatException`.

value given is: `1000000000000`

can any one tell me what is max value does the parsing can happen.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you are parsing.

Comment: @Suresh, the value used is: 1000000000000

Comment: Try like this : System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(""+Integer.MAX_VALUE));

Comment: @VijayKumar Yes. Integer overflow happened with your String.

Comment: There is no need of tag `Java ee`. Removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2147483647` is the maximum value `parseInt()` can parse without giving an exception. `1000000000000` > `2147483647`(=`Integer.MAX_VALUE`, Max value of `int`).`1000000000000` is no longer be an `int` value(can't represent as an `int` without [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)). So `partInt()` will give you `NumberFormatException`

You can use `Long.parseLong()` for larger values like here.

Eg:

```
Long.parseLong("1000000000000")
```

Comment: @downvoters, You should **at least** have courage to put a comment.

Comment: He is asking about the max value which can pass as the parameter value of the parse method. You are giving an alternative method to prevent from the NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 4):

It would be great, what value you are parsing. Coming to your actual value, you can parse the maximum value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Less than that value and which is in proper format will be parse nicely.

If you want to deal with greater values than that have a look at `Long` or `BigInteger`

Answer (score 3):

The maximum value of an integer is `2,147,483,647`. This is also the maximum value you can parse.

Consider to use `long` and `Long.parseLong()` if you need higher values.

Answer (score 2):

the max value is `2^31 - 1`, you can get it also in `Integer.MAX_VALUE`
Integer is a 32 bit number, 1 bit is sign bit ±, so `2^31 - 1`